# Can I control my Windows ITunes from other computer running Mac OS?

Tags: windows, mac, itunes, remote

I have two laptops running Itunes, I want to control my PC's Itunes from my Mac OS on the same Wifi network. Is there a possibility?

Comment: Sure; Use the remote desktop client of your choice to log into the Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [iTunes Remote Control (iTRC)](http://them.ws/itrc/):

> iTunes Remote Control (iTRC) is a network remote control for iTunes. It allows you to control iTunes on a remote machine with full track changing support and basic but functional playlist support. All you need to do it enable Remote Apple Events on the computer with iTunes on it and remember its network name.

Comment: Not sure Remote Apple Events is available on Windows, can't find any evidence of it being.

Comment: David, is it installed on Mac? So I don;t need any PC software? Just can't grab the idea. thanks!

Comment: @Anton yes installed on mac but as Tetsuijn points out it looks like the remote machine to be controlled may also need to be a mac and not windows ...